# Communicate between Windows and Linux subsystem using Virtual COM Port

Tags: linux, tty

I have a Windows program that connects to a COM port to send and receive data. The the other end is another program that is running on a remote Linux machine that also uses the COM port to communicate. I am trying to come up with the simplest way to bridge the connection between these two programs.

So far, I want to use the tty_bus utilities to create the COM port bridge over SSH. The problem I'm having is that I need to Windows side to have access to the bridged port. My thought was to create a virtual null-modem cable using com0com and then simply connect one end to my windows program and the other to the tty_bus utility on the Linux subsystem side. So, I tried creating a set of virtual COM ports using com0com and it "appears" that the COM port is not recognized by the Linux subsystem (or maybe I'm just doing something wrong). Is there a clean/better way to approach this?

Comment: how old is the program that it still works ANd uses com ports that are obsolete nowadays?

Comment: The program is a software that communicates directly to a device connected to the serial port on the remote machine. So far, I have split the serial port using the tty_bus utility so I can do some debugging on the device. But the test program is written in C# on windows and I need to forward the serial data to the local machine to connect to the windows program.

Comment: afaik exists tools and adapter that can emulate the COM via TCP but for that to work you need tobe in the same lan afaik. but i still miss here the Business Relation?